# How can I decompose $x^2(x-y)+y^2(y-z)+z^2(z-x)$ into at least two factors?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, multilinear-algebra

Decompose the following expression into at least two factors, and if it does not decompose, you must prove with mathematical reasoning why it does not decompose (be sure to say with a mathematical reason why it does not decompose)

$$x^2(x-y)+y^2(y-z)+z^2(z-x)$$

If we permute $x$ to $y$, $y$ to $z$ and $z$ to $x$ at the same time, the result of our decomposition will not change at all, and in addition, we can bring the solution to zero by doing so (by substituting the same mentioned expressions) and we can find the root calculated and I got the wrong factors which I think is a bit strange...

Comment: Your post is hard or not to understand, you write "I could go anywhere by myself." what does that mean?

Comment: Yes you are right .  My point was that, in my opinion, I have understood the basic idea of ​​the question to break this expression into its factors, but maybe there are better ideas.

Comment: If it has a factor $(x+py+qz)$ then the cyclic property would give factors $(z+px+qy)$ and $(y+pz+qx)$ and the polynomial itself would be $r(x+py+qz)(z+px+qy)(y+pz+qx)$ with $r=\frac 1{pq}$ by comparing the coefficient of $x^3$.

Comment: Can you write it as a multiple of several factors?

Answer (score 0):

Not probably what you want, but you can factor the expression like this:

$$\left(x-\frac{\sqrt[3]{-25 y^3+27 y^2 z+\sqrt{4 \left(-y^2-3 z^2\right)^3+\left(-25 y^3+27 y^2 z+9 y z^2-27 z^3\right)^2}+9 y
   z^2-27 z^3}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(-y^2-3 z^2\right)}{3 \sqrt[3]{-25 y^3+27 y^2 z+\sqrt{4 \left(-y^2-3
   z^2\right)^3+\left(-25 y^3+27 y^2 z+9 y z^2-27 z^3\right)^2}+9 y z^2-27 z^3}}-\frac{y}{3}\right) \left(x+\frac{\left(1-i
   \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{-25 y^3+27 y^2 z+\sqrt{4 \left(-y^2-3 z^2\right)^3+\left(-25 y^3+27 y^2 z+9 y z^2-27 z^3\right)^2}+9
   y z^2-27 z^3}}{6 \sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(-y^2-3 z^2\right)}{3\ 2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-25 y^3+27 y^2
   z+\sqrt{4 \left(-y^2-3 z^2\right)^3+\left(-25 y^3+27 y^2 z+9 y z^2-27 z^3\right)^2}+9 y z^2-27 z^3}}-\frac{y}{3}\right)
   \left(x+\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{-25 y^3+27 y^2 z+\sqrt{4 \left(-y^2-3 z^2\right)^3+\left(-25 y^3+27 y^2 z+9
   y z^2-27 z^3\right)^2}+9 y z^2-27 z^3}}{6 \sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(-y^2-3 z^2\right)}{3\ 2^{2/3}
   \sqrt[3]{-25 y^3+27 y^2 z+\sqrt{4 \left(-y^2-3 z^2\right)^3+\left(-25 y^3+27 y^2 z+9 y z^2-27 z^3\right)^2}+9 y z^2-27
   z^3}}-\frac{y}{3}\right)$$

Comment: May I ask, what sort of software did you use for that monstrosity!

Comment: @SahajSatishSharma Mathematica